# Incorrect username password 3 times java login form

Tags: forms, authentication

This is the code I have. It reads from a text file and compares it to the users input. How would I add to this if a username and password is entered 3 times then do something. I have tried putting a counter in many places but it doesn't work. Where would the counter go?

```
 Boolean login = false;
  while(read.nextLine() !=null){
    String user = read.next();
    String pass = read.next();
    read.next();
  if(usernameT.getText().equals(user) && 
    passwordT.getText().equals(pass)){
  login = true;
  break;                 
   }
 }
if(login)
new Menu();
else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect 
username or password");
usernameT.setText("");
passwordT.setText("");
 }
```

Comment: it would go at the top

Answer (score 0):

```
  int counter = 3;
 Boolean login = false;
  while(counter > 0 && read.nextLine() !=null){
    String user = read.next();
    String pass = read.next();
    read.next();
  if(usernameT.getText().equals(user) && 
    passwordT.getText().equals(pass)){
  login = true;
  break;                 
   }
   --counter;
 }
```

Comment: @ZaidEsmail I would expect so